# Showing sum of values with two decimals

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sum

I'm having a list of items where one attribute is of type decimal.

When I try to sum the items attribute and display it with two decimals it won't work when the sum is even.

For example:

If sum is 30000 I want it to display 30000.00, now it shows just 30000.

But if the sum is 30000.55 it displays 30000.55.

My view code:

```
for (var j = 0; j < Model.Calculation.Count; j++)
{
     @Model.Calculation[j].Sum(item => item.InterestAmount).ToString("#.##")
}
```

How can I make it show 30000.00 when the sum is 30000?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `"#.##"` as your format string, and `#` means "show a digit if it's significant". If you *always* want to show two digits, you should use `"0.00"` as your pattern. See the [documentation for custom numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details.

Sample code:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Show(0m);        // 0.00
        Show(0.123m);    // 0.12
        Show(123.456m);  // 123.46
        Show(-123.456m); // -123.46
    }

    static void Show(decimal value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0.00"));
    }
}
```

Note that this uses the current culture for formatting, so you could end up with "123,46" for example. If you *always* want a dot for the decimal separator, specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as the format provider.

Answer (score 1):

From [The "#" Custom Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SpecifierD)

> The "#" custom format specifier serves as a digit-placeholder symbol.
>   If the value that is being formatted has a digit in the position where
>   the "#" symbol appears in the format string, that digit is copied to
>   the result string. Otherwise, nothing is stored in that position in
>   the result string.
>
> **Note that this specifier never displays a zero that is not a
>   significant digit, even if zero is the only digit in the string. It
>   will display zero only if it is a significant digit in the number that
>   is being displayed.**

You might need to use `0.00` instead.

```
(30000).ToString("0.00") // Prints 30000.00
(30000.55).ToString("0.00") // Prints 30000.55
```

- [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Of course this `.ToString()` method uses current thread culture by default. That's why your decimal separator depends on your current culture. If you always want `.` as a decimal separator, you need to provide a culture that has `.` as a [`NumberDecimalSeparator` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.invariantinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Replace your  "#" with 0

```
for (var j = 0; j < Model.Calculation.Count; j++)
{
     @Model.Calculation[j].Sum(item => item.InterestAmount).ToString("0.00")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**A simpler and far more efficient way to achieve this.**

```
for (var j = 0; j < Model.Calculation.Count; j++)
{
     @Model.Calculation[j].Sum(item => item.InterestAmount).ToString("F")
}

//  F:   0.00 
//  F0:  0 
//  F1:  0.0 
//  F2:  0.00 
//  F3:  0.000
```

For more such formats related to numbers visit [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)